# Calculating the "distance" between two unordered sets

Tags: python, collections, set, distance, set-theory

Assume two sets (unordered, no duplicate elements):

```
A = set(["z", "x", "c"])
B = set(["x", "z", "d", "e"])
```

These sets have two common elements: "z" and "x", and some set-specific elements: c, d, e.

How can you give each set a score, just like string-distance, while

- disregarding the ordering of elements and
- imposing the no-duplicate
  constraint for each isolated set

?

As you can see in the example, the size of each set can be different.

The non-critical requirements for this algorithm are:

- Insertion > Deletion (a set lacking an element implies higher cost, than the one that has one too many) if possible, or just INS = DEL
- Swap: 0 (no cost, since ordering has no effect on distance)

For now I have been calculating a set distance score:

```
score_A = len(common(a,b)) / len(a)    # common(...) calculates intersection
score_B = len(common(a,b)) / len(b)

quadratic_score = sqrt(score_A * score_B)
```

How would you recommend approaching this problem or improving my solution?

Are there any algorithms that allow specification of costs?

---

Right now I am about to define a simple algebra for set modification:

```
def calculate_distance( a, b, insertion_cost=1, deletion_cost=1 ):
    """
    Virtually, a programmer-friendly set-minus.

    @return     the distance from A to B, mind that this is not
                a commutative operation.
    """
    score = 0
    for e in a:
        if e not in b: # implies deletion from A
            score += deletion_cost

    for e in b:
        if e not in a: # implies insertion into A
            score += insertion_cost

    return score
```

How can I normalize this value and against what?

Comment: _Those_ two sets you gave do not have "a" and "b" in common, more like "x" and "z"

Comment: @TheZ: Is there some asymmetry in your two sets? You have the requirement that `Insertion > Deletion` yet surely an insertion in one set could be interpreted as a deletion in the other, if they are both to be treated the same?

Comment: Insertion here is in terms of _point mutations_. It is a cost of making one set equal the other. So when comparing A _against_ B, A would require ONE DELETION and TWO INSERTIONS. While comparing B _against_ A, B would need TWO DELETIONS and just ONE INSERTION. If the costs are INS:2, DEL:1, the case (I) would demand: (1+4), while (II): (2+2). My background is set theory is lacking, but I would think it implies asymmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is of course out of date with respect to the question, but hopefully will be picked up by any future visitors.

Use the [Jaccard distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), the cardinality (size of set) of the symmetric difference between the two sets divided by the cardinality of their union. In other terms, union minus intersection all divided by union.

This assumes that the elements can be compared in a discrete fashion, i.e. they are equal or not. A desirable property is that the Jaccard distance is a [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 3):

How about the size of the set intersection over the size of the larger set? So:

```
float(len(A.intersection(B)))/max(len(A),len(B))
```

It'll give you a number scaled in the range 0.0 to 1.0 which is often desirable. 1.0 representing full equality, 0.0 representing nothing in common.

Answer (score 2):

Similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024086/distance-between-sets-even-when-the-sets-are-unbalanced)

Assuming OP is asking something as the "distance", I think it's better to make it **0** when two sets are identical according to [the general requirements of a distance function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#General_case)

And it would be also good to have *symmetric* and *triangle inequality*

*symmetric* is intuitive, and *triangle inequality* means d(A,C) ≤ d(A,B) + d(B,C)

I suggest something like:

```
C = A.intersection(B)
Distance = sqrt(len(A-C)*2 + len(B-C)*2)
```

However I don't know how to prove the *triangle inequality* yet

---

To normalize OP's updated function result, just do `score = score / (len(a) + len(b))`

which will give you 1 when `a` doesn't intersect `b`, and 0 when `a == b`

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits the requirement about variable cost. Does your last remark imply that the sum of all mutations or maximal point-mutation cost is never above the sum of elements in both sets? Ok, I can just multiply the len(a) + len(b) with the max(insertion_cost, deletion_cost)

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. The case where you can get highest `score` is `a` and `b` don't have any element in common, so `a` need to delete every element it has first, and then insert every element `b` has, which gives you the score `len(a) + len(b)`